# type object 'Animation' has no attribute 'mobject'

Tags: manim

I exercise examples [here](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/master/English/update_successions/update_successions.py)

From SuccessionExample1 on, as long as there exists:

```
Succession(Animation, Mobject(),...
```

There will be error like below:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Animation' has no attribute 'mobject'
```

I checked the animation.py and found self.mobject = mobject, that is, the Animation class has mobject attribute, are those samples obselete? or other causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that is the code for old versions (I use the February 3 version in my tutorials), I forgot to tell you in your previous question to render only the Update functions, not those of Successions. To use the Successions, the code format must be changed, [this is the code for the recent version](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/master/English/update_successions/successions_in_recent_versions.py).

In case of SuccessionExample1:

```py
class SuccessionExample1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        number_line=NumberLine(x_min=-2,x_max=2)
        text=TextMobject("Text")\
             .next_to(number_line,DOWN)
        dashed_line=DashedLine(
                                number_line.get_left(),
                                number_line.get_right(),
                                color=YELLOW,
                              ).set_stroke(width=11)

        self.add(number_line)
        self.wait(0.3)

        self.play(
                    LaggedStart(
                        *[ShowCreationThenDestruction(dashed_segment)
                        for dashed_segment in dashed_line],
                        run_time=5
                    ),
                    AnimationGroup(
                        Animation(Mobject(),run_time=2.1),
                        Write(text),lag_ratio=1
                    )
            )
        self.wait()
```